# Only allow keyof a certain type

Tags: typescript, generics, keyof

I have this simple function for sorting objects by date. But currently I have to check if the field actually is a date, before doing the comparison. Is there a way to limit `K` to only allow keys that are of a certain type, in this case `Date`?

```js
const compareDate = <T, K extends keyof T>(key: K) => (x: T, y: T) => {
  const v = x[key];
  const w = y[key];
  return v instanceof Date && w instanceof Date ? v.getTime() - w.getTime() : 0;
};

list.sort(compareDate('dateField'));
```

What I would want is:

```js
const compareDate = <T, K extends ???>(key: K) => (x: T, y: T) => {
  // ts should know and only allow x[key] and y[key] to be of type Date here:
  return x[key].getTime() - y[key].getTime();
}

const list = [{a: 1, b: 'foo', c: new Date}];

list.sort(compareDate('a')); // <-- ts should refuse this
list.sort(compareDate('b')); // <-- ts should refuse this
list.sort(compareDate('c')); // <-- ts should allow this
```

Is there a way to express this in Typescript

Answer (score 8):

You can use a mapped type to get all `Date` props of a type:

```js
type DateProps<T> = ({ [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Date ? P : never })[keyof T];
```

And then use that instead of `keyof T`:

```js
const compareDate = <T extends Record<K, Date>, K extends DateProps<T>>(key: K) => (x: T, y: T) => {
    return x[key].getTime() - x[key].getTime();
};
```

Borrowing the `Record` idea from @ford04 we can even ensure that TypeScript is aware of the type of `x[key]` and `y[key]`. Meaning there is no `instanceof` check or casting necessary inside the function.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsCAFATgezAZwDwBUB8UAvFABQDeUA2klAJYB2UA1hCGgGZS4C6AXNxo8oEAB6IGAE0ywE0APxRaAhhABuEFFAC+ASiqt2XXgG4AUGYDGaBpmBRrAWzBwUEeImJQ8I8RCkyAEoQ1iiS2ADSADSyiPgxEb4S0rHI6Fh4+PikhgIRusSEpKICuDEgpQVEhORmUFBuwACuKEyiBmw8AHQA5hDAuHSOEKQFALRQ7YbdfQNDI7rm2hbWtvYANnR2XlTkcAIAjDEARgIA5BxoaGcxlioQAO6p2jzmZpt2XZhoKMCkTi43B4Rmc4GddIsoAB6KHeMYTYAyTAACzQTXWkgaEA4TUw0GAyK27y2wC+Pz+ANc7jkpDOx3BkJhcIRSNR6MxbhxeKgBKJH1J31+-zQzipwNplgZJmhsOw8J5rLRGKgcHW6zQT15mCAA)

Comment: That does limit the key name as I want, but Typescript still doesn't know that `x[key]` is of type `Date`? Is there a way to tell Typescript that too?

Comment: You're right I just noticed that as well. I'm not sure that's possible, you might have to cast them. Will update the answer if I find something though.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry. I don't think there is a way to get it to work without the `instanceof` check or casting (as seen in my updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `T` extending `Record<K, Date>` type, where `K` is some string key of this record. When you invoke `compareDate` with a key `K`, that does not point to a `Date` value inside the record, you get the desired type error.

```
const compareDate = <T extends Record<K, Date>, K extends string>(key: K) => (
  x: T,
  y: T
) => x[key].getTime() - y[key].getTime();

const list = [{ a: 1, b: "foo", c: new Date() }];

list.sort(compareDate("a")); // <-- error
list.sort(compareDate("b")); // <-- error
list.sort(compareDate("c")); // <-- works!
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBKC2AHAhgJwKYBFlXTAvDADwAqM6AHrmACYQwBK6oqNRA0gDQza4B83duSrpa9aKgCWYAOZ8AFAGt0ATwBcMdgEoCfGPIBQMGBQ0lORmOpgkDO-HooBtZSoC6AOhnooJSfHR5HQBaKxdVT29ff0CtAG4DA1BIWAAbSWgCGCcAbxhkDQBGbgAjDQAiADMQEHLuYA0wdAB3HhxYmABfNwSDdOgPCBBUKHkEFAxeQPLkcq14mAB6ReJg0PRUVGG+jKhB4dHxtCx2+XKSuYXl1fXN7f69oZGxkCRjqbPgS7illaI1mDNYaKCAAQgMQA)

Comment: When I changed the generics to this from what I had via @lukasgeiter, it no longer worked, so seems the `Record` type is more limiting in some way? Also, you still have the `instanceof` check. 

Comment: @Svish sorry, had forgotten to drop the instanceof operator, there is no cast/instanceof necessary. The Record type just ensures, that the key you pass in leads to Date values in `x` and `y`. When you define the key as in the other answer, the problem is that the compiler cannot make a connection between `T` and `K`. In this case you would have to cast. Answer is now updated.

Comment: In the answer from @lukasgeiter, TypeScript compiler cannot statically analyze and infer the type `T` for `x` and `y` in the function body, because `T` is not restricted. `T` and the conditional type `DateProps<T>` cannot be evaluated until a concrete list and item types are given for which you invoke `list.sort`.

Comment: @ford04 I have to agree that using `Record` for this is a good idea. Combining it with my existing answer results in the best of both worlds IMO. The advantage of restricting the type of `key` directly is that the error message is much clearer and even autocompletion works. @Svish see my updated answer now with `Record` and without casts.